# It is possible to create a Desktop app using Java and Electron JS?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, electron, frontend

I'd like to build a Desktop application for drawing. I've already the model and controller written in Java and now, i'm gonna make the view. I don't want to use JavaFX for the ForntEnd of my application. Instead, I'd like to use Electron... it is possible? and how?

If I'm saying stupid things please forgive me and tell my what is wrong with my idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can build a desktop app using Electron. Any Electron website app could be made to run as a Desktop application. I recommend checking out some of the apps on Electron's website: https://www.electronjs.org/apps

Some of them which are open source have links to their GitHub repositories which would be useful to see how they operate. A simple one to start with would be the Trivia Bot one they have on the page I mentioned: https://github.com/Trivia-Bot-Apps/trivia-desktop

As for how to do it yourself, I'd recommend searching YouTube or other resources for Electron tutorials as there are many. Even if they are showing how to create an Electron app in a web browser you can still follow the majority of their process for making a desktop application.